# Can one make a diagonalizable matrix from a non-diagonalizable square matrix by adding its symmetric part?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M$ be a (real) non-diagonalizable square matrix, and $S=\frac{1}{2}(M+M^T)$ the symmetric part of $M$. Is the matrix $M+S$ always diagonalizable? This is easily verified to be true if $M$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix. Can someone provide a proof or a counterexample for $n\times n$ matrices with $n>2$?

Note: Let $M=S+A$, with $A=\frac{1}{2}(M-M^T)$ the antisymmetric part of $M$. Let $Q$ be an orthogonal matrix that diagonalizes $S$, and put $Q^TSQ=\Lambda$ and $Q^TAQ=B$. The question can then be restated as: given an antisymmetric square matrix $B$ and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ with $B+\Lambda$ non-diagonalizable, is $B+2\Lambda$ diagonalizable?

Thanks!

[This question arises naturally in research work I am doing; a positive answer to the question would lead to considerable progress.]

Comment: To be clear, when you say "diagonalizable", do you mean over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Assuming that you mean "diagonalizable" with potentially complex eigenvalues: my hunch is that we can guarantee that $B + \alpha \Lambda$ will be diagonalizable for "most" values of $\alpha \geq 0$, but not necessarily that this will hold for $\alpha = 1$.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: thanks for asking for clarification: I meant diagonalizability over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: yes, I had been thinking further along the same line, and tended to see it as a problem: given an antisymmetric (thus diagonalizable) matrix $A$ and diagonal matrix $\Lambda$, can one say something about the nature of the set $\{t\in\mathbb{R}|A+t\Lambda\;\textrm{is non-diagonalizable over}\;\mathbb{C}\}$?

Comment: @Lode I suspect that we can deduce that $\{t \in \Bbb R | A + t\Lambda\}$ is finite, and that one can prove this as a consequence of the fact that diagonalizability is [generic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_property) (i.e. the diagonalizable matrices form a dense and open set in the Zariski topology over $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$).  I'm not fluent in the tools of algebraic geometry though, so I'm not confident about this.

Comment: @Lode I meant the set of $A$ such that $A + t\Lambda$ fails to be diagonalizable.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, this set should certainly be finite, since a non-diagonalizable matrix $M$ possesses degenerate eigenvalues (lying in $\mathbb{C}$), and hence the discriminant, $d(M)$, of its characteristic polynomial should vanish; see, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant. This discriminant is a polynomial in the coefficients of the matrix (even with integer coefficients). Applied to $A+t\Lambda$ one thus gets $d(A+t\Lambda)=0$; the left hand side is a polynomial in $t$ (with real coefficients), and the result follows.

Comment: @Lode Ah, the discriminant is a great way to go here.  So with that being said, it suffices to select an $\alpha > 0$ that is sufficiently large.  To find such an $\alpha$ systematically, you might want to look at the eigenvalue inequalities for the sum of Hermitian and skew-Hermitian matrices given in Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false in general.  Fix a non-diagonalizable matrix $M$ with symmetric part $S$ and antisymmetric part $A$.  Now consider the block matrices $$S'=\begin{pmatrix} S & 0 \\ 0 & S/2\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$A'=\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & A\end{pmatrix}.$$  Then $M'=S'+A'$ is not diagonalizable because its top left block is $M$, but $M'+S'$ is not diagonalizable either since its bottom right block is $M$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this indeed provides a nice counterexample! At the same it raises a new question: your construction gives counterexamples for even $n$; could one construct a counterexample for odd $n$ as well?

Comment: @Lode We can simply add a final row and column of zeros to both matrices

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: oh...yes, of course. Meanwhile I figured out that Eric's construction can be straightforwardly generalized: let $M_1=S_1+A_1$ and $M_2=S_2+A_2$ be two square non-diagonalizable matrices of dimension $n_1$ and $n_2$ respectively, written in their symmetric/antisymmetric decomposition. The diagonal block matrices $S'=\textrm{diag}(S_1,S_2/t)$ and $A'=\textrm{diag}(A_1,A_2)$, with $t\in\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$, are of dimension $n=n_1+n_2$, and we have that $S'+A'$ and $S'+tA'$ are both non-diagonalizable.